# how to check if file with same name but with different extension exists in a directory Powershell

Tags: powershell, timestamp, compare, exists

I am trying to find two things here. I have thousands of files in a folder. lets take example of one file and We can apply same logic to all files

1. If file with same name but with different extension exists.
2. If it exists, I need to compare the lastwritetime or the timestamp to find out which file is newer.

For example, if I have a file `culture.txt` I supposed to have a corresponding file `culture.log`.

If I have `culture.txt` but `culture.log` file is missing, then its an issue, so I want to output names of all .txt file for which corresponding .log files are missing.

If both `culture.txt` and `culture.log` are available, then I want to check if the `culture.txt` was generated after `culture.log`. If `culture.txt` is generated before `culture.log`, there is an issue so, I need to output the names of such .txt files with this issue saying "Culture.txt was generated before culture.log- Please rerun the program".

**Anyone who can help would be appreciated. Thank You.**

A little more help needed on same question if I can get. The code suggested by Esperento is completely working fine but the requirement is updated. In a folder, I have multiple files with multiple extensions and not limited to just .txt and .log.  I can have .doc, .docx, .xls and many other files in the same folder. 
Now about updated requirement. I have to look for file names with 3 specific extensions only. One of them is program file. Which should be generated first obviously. Let’s say Culture.prog. then when I run the Culture.Prog two files will be generated like culture.log first and culture.txt respectively. 
So obviously, the timestamp on prog is older than log and timestamp on log is older than txt which generated very last. 
We have to check the availability of 2 corresponding files(log and prog) in reference to .txt file only which is generated last. 
So, first check is, if 2 corresponding files are available for .txt file. Next check is the timestamp is corresponding for these 3 files in order. We have to output only if one of the condition is not satisfied, otherwise its ok if we don’t output anything. For example, if for culture.txt, if .log or .prog file is missing we have to output the fact that which or both files are missing. If the time stamp of txt file is older than log and/or prog we have to output that fact. I hope I am clear in my request. Thank you

Comment: This is a fairly straightforward task. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried various codes, for example $log = (gci -Filter *.log  | % {$_.BaseName})
$txt = (gci -Filter *.txt  | % {$_.BaseName})| where {$log.basename -eq $_.basename}
[string]$Data = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $txt -DifferenceObject $log -Property Name,LastWriteTime | Sort-Object Name |Out-String
foreach-object |{
if ($log-$_.Lastwritetime) -gt ($txt-$_.Lastwritetime)
Write-Host "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxl"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
#list file and group by name without extension
Get-ChildItem "C:\temp\test" -file -filter "*.*" | group Basename | 
%{ 
    $group= $_.group   

    # if not same name, missing message
    if ($_.Count -eq 1)
    {
       "'{0}' are missing" -f $group.Name 
    }
    #else search into current group file with great creation time and print message
    else
    {
       $group | % {$file=$_; $group | %{if ($_.CreationTime -gt  $file.CreationTime) {"'{0}' has beeen generated before '{1} " -f $file.Name, $_.Name} } }
    }

} | out-file "C:\temp\test\result.txt"
```

Comment: Thank you so much Esperento. Your help is truly appreciated. Its working nice.